# FoodTracker, Swift 3 and open var

Tags: ios, swift3

I'm trying to do the apple Swift tutorial FoodTracker in Swift 3. In [part 5](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson5.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH19-SW1) I'm told to override IntrinsicContentSize() as follows:

```
override func intrinsicContentSize() -> CGSize {
  return CGSize(width: 240, height: 44)
}
```

The only problem is that the UIView does not have any such function in Swift 3. Instead it has been replaced with

```
open var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize { get }
```

Can anyone please point me in the right direction to achieve the result in the tutorial linked above?

Comment: Instead of overriding the method you now have to override the property, but in the end it's the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the property to return the size:

```
override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    get {
        return CGSize(width: 240, height: 44)
    }
}
```

As you have a readonly variable, you can leave out the get block and just return the size:

```
override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 240, height: 44)
}
```